# Prevent duplicate POST API calls across multiple servers

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

Lets say that I have a SPA application to manage user details (name,age,etc.. ) with the following structure:

SPA <-->  my-api-servcie.com VIP <--> [my-api-server-1.com, my-api-server-2.com]

The API is built with SpringBoot, Java, Spring JDBC, oracle 12c

I want to enforce the name to be unique. However, I do not have control over the DB schema and I can not add unique constraint to the name column. Anyway, I did implement the following preventive measures:

- Front-end level

  - validation to prevent  duplicate names
  - layover full screen spinner to prevent accidental clicks
- API level

  - validation to prevent  duplicate names

With all of the above in mined, one of the application users managed to send 2 POST request both of which were successful passing all of the above validations.

The calls looked something like this, where each request took a couple of milliseconds to complete:

```
POST my-api-server-1.com/user {name:"Sam"} at 15-JUN-18 02.11.20.000000000 PM
POST my-api-server-2.com/user {name:"Sam"} at 15-JUN-18 02.11.23.000000000 PM
```

**First** it seems odd that both requests were successful even though they were almost 2 seconds apart. So technically the second call should not have passed validation at the API level. What would have been the reason for this behavior? Is there some short-term cashing the JDBC or Oracle layer?

**Second**, what are other preventive measures I could have done other than adding DB constraint?

I could use synchronized method, but that would have caused some performance consequences.

Comment: Synchronize access based on username

Comment: That would work if you are using on server. However, in this I'm using multiple servers

Comment: But you can use another centralized database to syncronize only access only. Or use separate centralized service to do user registration only. Also you can use eg Hazelcast to sync java constructs across clusters. As last resort, use table locking.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronisation is not feasible in your case, because you clearly state that you are working with two application servers. A synchronized method running in two different VMs is clearly not synchronized between these two VMs.

Further I don't know the exact details of your implementation (perhaps you can share an anonymized version of your `application.properties`) but it is very likely that you have a Hibernate cache enabled.

These caches act completely transparent this means when your applications queries an entity it is very likely that this entity is served from cache instead of the database. In your case again, you are working with two application servers, each working with their own database cache.

Comment: Yes you are   right  Synchronisation  would not solve my issue in this case. I'm using Spring JDBC . There is no Hibernate in my case.

Comment: OK, I've missed that bit.